# FOR loop variables and commands are not getting interpreted properly in .BAT Windows 10

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, windows-10

OS: Windows 10.

I'm learning BATCH scripting. I was trying to apply FOR loop and IF conditions to sort my music collection. My music folder (with subdirs) has possible *duplicates* of .mp3 files as .aac files (similar in filenames only, not binary). Using .BAT script, I decided to try moving such *duplicate* .aac files to an "aac" directory within each directory/subdirectory having the original .mp3 file.

**The code I used is as follows:**

> ```
> @echo on
> FOR %%B in ('dir /b /s *.mp3') do (
>   FOR %%A in ('dir /b /s *.aac') DO (
>     IF %%~nB==%%~nA (move %%A "%%~dpBaac\")
>   )
> )
> pause
> ```

**The output**

```
E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>FOR %B in ('dir /b /s *.mp3') do (FOR %A in ('dir /b /s *.aac') DO (IF %~nB == %~nA (move %A "%~dpBaac\" ) ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(FOR %A in ('dir /b /s *.aac') DO (IF 'dir == %~nA (move %A "E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy\aac\" ) ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF 'dir == 'dir (move 'dir "E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF 'dir == b (move /b "E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy\aac\" ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF 'dir == s (move /s "E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy\aac\" ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(FOR %A in ('dir /b /s *.aac') DO (IF b == %~nA (move %A "E:\aac\" ) ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF b == 'dir (move 'dir "E:\aac\" ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF b == b (move /b "E:\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF b == s (move /s "E:\aac\" ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(FOR %A in ('dir /b /s *.aac') DO (IF s == %~nA (move %A "E:\aac\" ) ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF s == 'dir (move 'dir "E:\aac\" ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF s == b (move /b "E:\aac\" ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF s == s (move /s "E:\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I know that

> FOR **/F**

parameter won't suit my case, but when used, it substitutes the %%variables with part of foldername and the IF condition is also run.

```
E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(FOR /F %A in ('dir /b /s *.aac') DO (IF ##########YOUTUBE == %~nA (move %A "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) ) )

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF ##########YOUTUBE == ##########YOUTUBE (move E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF ##########YOUTUBE == ##########YOUTUBE (move E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF ##########YOUTUBE == ##########YOUTUBE (move E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF ##########YOUTUBE == ##########YOUTUBE (move E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF ##########YOUTUBE == ##########YOUTUBE (move E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) )
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE RIPS - Copy>(IF ##########YOUTUBE == ##########YOUTUBE (move E:\AUDIO\##########YOUTUBE "E:\AUDIO\aac\" ) )
^CThe system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: You have to use `for /F` - with the option string `"delims="` in your situation - to process the output of a command like `dir`. Alternatively use `for /R`. Nevertheless, you have two nested loops which is not necessary; simply loop through `*.mp3` files in one loop and check for equally named `*.aac` files using `if exist "%%~nI.aac" 2> nul md "%%~dpIaac" & move "%%~I" "%%~dpIaac"` (assuming `%%I` is the loop variable)...

Comment: You will also need ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: No, @cup, he will not since there are no environment variables involved...

Comment: @aschipfl using for /R doesn't help. In addition, it messes up the filename to be copied in the move command.

Comment: Is `aac` supposed to be a subdirectory under each directory containing a `.mp3` file?

Comment: @lit, yes, aac folder needs to be created at runtime as a subdir there, provided a duplicate exists

Comment: @aschipfl I made it work, however I had to remove the nested FOR and use for /F with delims

Comment: No, type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help text. You'll find out that `for /F` can read text files but it can also capture the output of commands, which is exactly the case in your situation. By the way, using the quotes around `delims=` avoids necessity of escaping by `^`...

Comment: @VaisakMohan, I have rolled back your latest edit. Please do not use the question area to include a solution. If you wish future readers to view your solution, please post it, with the associated information as an answer in the appropriate location. If you later choose it as your preferred solution, you could then mark it as accepted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer that worked for me, suggested by @aschipfl in comments.

> You have to use for /F - with the option string "delims=" in your situation - to process the output of a command like dir. Nevertheless, you have two nested loops which is not necessary; simply loop through *.mp3 files in one loop and check for equally named *.aac files using if exist "%%~nI.aac" 2> nul md "%%~dpIaac" & move "%%~I" "%%~dpIaac" (assuming %%I is the loop variable).

Hence the final code:

```
@echo on
FOR /f delims^=, %%I in ('dir /b /s *.ogg') do (
  if exist "%%~nI.mp3" 2> nul md "%%~dpIogg" & move "%%~I" "%%~dpIogg"
    )
pause
```

Still not sure why using nested for loop instead of the if conditional in above code failed to work.